# Some Android devices skip the onTouchEvent when the finger is not moved

Tags: android, events, touch

I'm trying to make an android game where the player moves the character by touching anywhere on the screen, holding the touch and draging the finger in any direction.
So I made 2 points to store the coordinates of the touches. One for the coordinates of the beginning of the touch event and one for the position the finger is on right now.
With my Asus transformer pad (Android 4.2 then and now 4.3) this works great. But on 2 smartphones (Some LG with Android 4.0 and my Nexus 5 with 4.4) the touch event stops when the finger is not moved for a frame.
It seems the onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) is not called then.

This is the onTouchEvent function:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (getHolder()) {

            if (getTouchStart() == null)
                setTouchStart(new CPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));

            setTouch(new CPoint(event.getX(), event.getY()));


        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is what's called while drawing:

```
if (getTouch() != null)
{
    [unimportant drawing stuff]
}
else
    setTouchStart(null);

setTouch(null);
```

(CPoint is my Point class that stores the coordinates of the touches)

So on the two other devices the onTouchEvent function is only called, when the player moved the finger since the last rendered frame. Else the touch event is finished and when moving a new one is created.

Is there a way how to avoid this behavior? The onTouchEvent should work on every device

//Sorry for my bad english

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I'd like to avoid the problem above. I need to know why the onTouch doesn't fire on some devices if the finger is not moved for one frame